# How to set quiet period as other Jenkins parameter?

Tags: jenkins

I'd like this job to wait a certain amount of seconds based off of a string parameter given to the job. The field only allows me to enter numbers, so I cannot use $(PARAM). I want to know what would be a good way to do this.

P.S:
Do jobs in quiet period hang executors?

Comment: Can you clarify the type of job you are running?  I don't understand what you mean by "the field only allows me to enter numbers".

Comment: @WillBrode The quiet period field only allows for numbers to be entered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) job that takes in the parameter and then triggers your job, setting the quiet period in the [build step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) (see quietPeriod at the bottom).  Like this:

```
node {
    build job: 'foo',
          quietPeriod: params.QuietPeriod as int,
          wait: false
}
```

Where you've defined QuietPeriod as the parameter with the number of seconds to wait.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering about the
'P.S: Do jobs in quiet period hang executors?'
part of the original question:

No, executors are not occupied during this quiet period.